# Using .text() jquery to display text within a span

Tags: jquery, text, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hel"></div>
<script>
txt="<script>alert('Test');</script>";
var headerIcon = '<div>hi</div>';
var messageBox = $("<div class='textDiv'><span class='sp'></span></div>");

$(document).ready(function(){
messageBox.text(txt);
//$(".textDiv .sp").text(txt);
$('#hel').append(headerIcon,messageBox);

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is

```
hi
<script>alert("Test");</script>
```

But if I use $(".textDiv .sp").text(txt); instead of messageBox.text(txt); the output is only 
hi
What is going wrong when i use $(".textDiv .sp").text(txt);?

Edit : I dont want to inject html.I want to display as text only. But i just want to know why messageBox.text(txt); works but $(".textDiv .sp").text(txt); doesnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this. As far as I understand you, it should help:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#hel').append(headerIcon,messageBox);
   $(".textDiv .sp").text(txt);
}
```

`$(".textDiv .sp")` is in message box when you call `$(".textDiv .sp").text(txt)`, but not in a DOM. That is why it finds nothing (`$(".textDiv .sp")` will search only elements already in DOM). Another approach:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".textDiv .sp", messageBox).text(txt);
       $('#hel').append(headerIcon,messageBox);       
    }
```

`$(".textDiv .sp", messageBox).text('txt');` - second param here strictly say that jQuery should search inside `messageBox`. It is eqvivalent `to messageBox.find(".textDiv .sp").text("txt");`

And just like it was mentioned by other users - in case you want to get `"<script>alert("Test");</script>"` executed - you should use `.html` instead of `.text`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#hel').append(headerIcon,messageBox);
   $(".textDiv .sp").text(txt);
} This is what you meant right? It worked :) You are an angel :)

Comment: Please edit your answer.Remove the line  messageBox.text(txt);

Comment: Yeah. I already edited my answer to reflect that. Plus take a look at other options. Could be useful.

Comment: @user930514 Besides, in your initial code there was a `XMLHTTPRequest` part. Take a look at `jQuery.ajax` function (just in case you do not know about it already)

Answer (score 6):

`text()` is escaping html tags, if you need to inject html into your document, then use `html()`
http://api.jquery.com/html/

Edit : I believe `$(".textDiv .sp").text(txt);` is not working because the element hasn't been injected into the DOM at that stage, and you're trying to select it from the DOM

Try to `console.log( $(".textDiv .sp") )`, and see what that returns.

Comment: I dont want to inject html.I want to display as text only. But i just want to know why messageBox.text(txt); works but $(".textDiv .sp").text(txt); doesnt

Answer (score 1):

instead of

> $(".textDiv .sp").text(txt); ,

use

> $(".textDiv .sp").html(txt);.

When you use `.text()` the browser will not parse into html whatever you want to place there. it will be displayed as a simple text. So just use `.html()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Btw you have a failure in your quoting:

```
 txt="<script>alert("Test");</script>";
```

You have eigher to escape the slashes in the string or to use single quotes

```
txt="<script>alert(\"Test\");</script>"; //or
txt="<script>alert('Test');</script>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the quotes around *test*. You need to escape it with single quotes rather than double quotes.

```
txt="<script>alert('Test');</script>";
```